# How to associate a file extension with a Windows command (not path)?

Tags: windows-7, file-association

In Windows 7, I want to associate `.tex` files with `latex`, which is in PATH. The association should work even if the binary is moved to another place in PATH. Can that be accomplished without associating the file extension with a custom batch script?

Comment: Surely you'd want to associate them with your text editor rather than latex?

Comment: @James: No, I want to compile/typeset them on double-click. I have several text editors without a mapped `pdflatex` key, and compile more often than I start editing.

Comment: I'd suggest using a better editor, but other than that, you'd probably want a batch file to be able to run on double-click. You could also just use the commmand line - once you write the command once, up + enter will repeat the compile process. Also look at `texi2dvi` to run twice and with bibtex to resolve all references.

Comment: @James: Using the command line would not solve my problem at all. Feel free to edit my question to make it more general if the latex example bothers you.

Comment: OK I understand now. `latex` isn't in PATH, the folder that contains all of the various `*tex` *executables* is in PATH, so windows knows to look there for them. So you could associate with the `.exe` files, but I don't think you could pass parameters to the command with an association.